# How can I bring back all the entries instead of only the first one?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm pretty new to python and am still learning programming in general.

I'm looking to webscrape titles and artists from this page: https://www.billboard.com/charts/country-airplay/1990-01-20

and arrange them into a tabluar format.

I've been able to pull the items with bs4/requests with the following:

```
for title in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__title'}):
    print(title.text)

for artist in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__artist'}):
    print(artist.text)
```

But when I try to set the object into a variable, it only brings back the first item.

```
title1 = title.text
print(title1)
```

How can I bring back all the tiems?

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.billboard.com/charts/country-airplay/1990-01-20')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for title in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__title'}):
    print(title.text)

for artist in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__artist'}):
    print(artist.text)

title1 = title.text
print(title1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a loop using this class `chart-list-item` and then specify the fields within that loop you would like to grab. Given that the following script should produce `rank`, `artist` and `album` names.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.billboard.com/charts/country-airplay/1990-01-20')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all(class_="chart-list-item"):
    rank = item.find(class_="chart-list-item__rank").get_text(strip=True)
    artist = item.find(class_="chart-list-item__artist").get_text(strip=True)
    album = item.find(class_="chart-list-item__title-text").get_text(strip=True)
    print(rank,artist,album)
```

Output are like:

```
1 Clint Black Nobody's Home
2 Tanya Tucker My Arms Stay Open All Night
3 Ricky Van Shelton Statue Of A Fool
4 Alabama Southern Star
5 Keith Whitley It Ain't Nothin'
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`zip`**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) function to combine the data.

`i.text.strip()` takes out trailing new lines `/n`.

```
import pandas as pd   
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.billboard.com/charts/country-airplay/1990-01-20')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')    

title = [i.text.strip() for i in  (soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__title'}))]
artist =  [i.text.strip() for i in (soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__artist'}))]

print(list(zip(artist,title)))
```

### output

```
[('Clint Black', "Nobody's Home"), ('Tanya Tucker', 'My Arms Stay Open All Night'),........]
```

---

### When using Pandas to save data in Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd   
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.billboard.com/charts/country-airplay/1990-01-20')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')    

title = [i.text.strip() for i in  (soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__title'}))]
artist =  [i.text.strip() for i in (soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'chart-list-item__artist'}))]

data = list(zip(title, artist))
dt = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['', 'title', 'artist'])
print(dt)
```

### Output

```
                                       Title                             Artist

0                                   Nobody's Home                        Clint Black
1                     My Arms Stay Open All Night                       Tanya Tucker
2                                Statue Of A Fool                  Ricky Van Shelton
3                                   Southern Star                            Alabama
4                                It Ain't Nothin'                      Keith Whitley
5                                  It's You Again                         Skip Ewing
6                   When I Could Come Home To You                      Steve Wariner
7                  Many A Long & Lonesome Highway                     Rodney Crowell
8                         That Just About Does It                        Vern Gosdin
9                            Start All Over Again               The Desert Rose Band
10                              Out Of Your Shoes                      Lorrie Morgan
11                              On Second Thought                      Eddie Rabbitt
12                                  One Man Woman                          The Judds
13                   Till I Can't Take It Anymore                    Billy Joe Royal
14                              Overnight Success                      George Strait
15                              Where've You Been                       Kathy Mattea
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great solution! learned a lot just reading it too